# What happened if I didn't add a dot at the end of `git checkout [commit]`?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'd like to view previous version of code. And choose to use the `git checkout [commit]` command to roll the workspace back to the target version.

I tried both `git checkout [commit]` and `git checkout [commit] .`. With or without the tailing dot, the workspace can both be rolled back.

So what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is very simple, and integral to how git thinks..

```
git branch
* master
git checkout [commit]
git branch
* (no branch)
git status
<no changes>
```

Here, you asked git to switch to an un-named branch based on the [commit].  It did so, and you have a clean working directory ready for you to name your branch.  **`git checkout master`** will take you home again.

```
git branch
* master
git checkout [commit] -- .
git branch
* master
git status
<lots of changes>
```

Here you asked git to extract the contents of [commit] and splatter them all over your working directory, all ready for you to do whatever you want with the files.  '**`git reset --hard HEAD; git clean -f -d -x`**' will take you home again.

Comment: Is there any difference between `git checkout [commit] .` and `git checkout [commit] -- .`?

Comment: The `git checkout` man page shows that -- separates [commits] from [paths].   The -- is optional, and is really important if you have a file who's name can be confused with a hash, a branch name, a tag or anything git considers special